# Circuit protection from voltage spike

Tags: tvs, back-emf

In order to suppress the voltage spike getting from an AC single phase motor (it is an exhaust type fan connected to 10 A relay) can somebody please guide me to select a proper protection device.

To power the relays, ESP32 & other components in the circuit I'm using a SMPS (Easypower brand) rated 5 V/2 A. The main input from AC (230 V) is connected to input of SMPS & COM terminal of all the relays. When the fan is switched OFF the input line of SMPS gets disturbed and ESP32 gets stuck.

After connecting a MOV (14D561K) across the relay contacts it worked fine when I switched OFF the fan but after few days the same problem arise but not always. In my case I don't know how much back emf is generated by the AC motor & how much current the protection device has to withstand.

I have read that TVS diode do not degrade over time. So, can I use a TVS diode in my application? If yes, can someone guide me to select a proper
TVS diode.
Forgive me if I'm wrong somewhere, this is my first post.
Thank you

TVS diode datasheet link-
[https://m.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/tvs_diodes/littelfuse_tvs_diode_p6ke_datasheet.pdf.pdf](https://m.littelfuse.com/%7E/media/electronics/datasheets/tvs_diodes/littelfuse_tvs_diode_p6ke_datasheet.pdf.pdf)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show a schematic showing all earth/grounds and link data sheets for all main parts.

Comment: Datasheet & schematic link - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11zZhSHpmuTHJjsk_t1GCa2Ex4WP2YbRs?usp=sharing  

I'm supplying input voltage of 230V AC to the SMPS. The TVS diode mentioned in the datasheet of SMPS is connected directly below X2 capacitor.
The PCB of ESP32 is connected above this relay PCB with berg strips due to some size constraints.

Comment: You could just use the same parts as in the reference application. You could look up all documentation available for the SMPS - there might be an EMI certified implementation. The glitches may not only be cured by the TVS - maybe the EMI-Choke is required after all. And please make sure there are Back-EMF diode in the relay drive cricuits.

Comment: Hello ElectronicsStudent, thank you for your response.
I tried connecting 10mH AC line filter as mentioned in its datasheet but still the same issue.
For the ULN2003 part in the datasheet it is mentioned that there are internal protection diodes for driving relays. Do I also need to connect it across the relay coil externally?